# mysql_query() Strange behaviour

Tags: php, mysql

I have a piece of **PHP** code which calls to `mysql_query()` to insert a row in a remote database.

The strange thing is that `mysql_query()` always returns **false** but when I check my database I can see that the row was inserted properly.

My PHP version is 5.4.3 and this is the code I´m using:

```
class dbmanager{

    public function executeQuery($sql){
       $con = mysql_connect(config::getBBDDServer(), config::getBBDDUser(), config::getBBDDPwd());
       if (!$con){
           die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
       }

       mysql_select_db(config::getBBDDName(), $con);

       $result = mysql_query($sql);

       mysql_close($con);

       return $result;
    }
}
```

// ANOTHER FILE...

```
private function insertRow($name, $descrip){
    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO myTable (name, descripction) VALUES ('%s', '%s')", mysql_real_escape_string($name), mysql_real_escape_string($description));    

    $db = new dbmanager();
    $result = $db->executeQuery($sql);

    if($result){ // always FALSE
        return mysql_insert_id();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Anybody has an idea about what is happening here?

Comment: Opening and closing the database every time you want to run a query seems like a bad idea.

Comment: You might want to inspect the possible error using `mysql_error()` (actually, `mysqli_error()`). Also, you are using the deprecated MySQL, you should use MySQLi instead.

Comment: Just a side comment: Rewrite your code! Do **not** use any of the `mysql_*` functions. They' ll be removed soon and are now soft deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You close connection to DB

```
mysql_close($con);
```

after that you try to call

```
mysql_insert_id();
```

Of course, it will return false.

Try to use

```
public function __destruct () {
    mysql_close($con);
}
```

instead of

```
mysql_close($con);
```

in your class.

Comment: In this case, also put mysql_connect in constructor.